# Why did the RHIC luminosity decrease after 2010?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

[This physics today article](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/PT.3.4452) about particle accelerator operation contains this figure, showing the evolution of peak luminosity over time for major proton-proton and proton-antiproton colliders. Notably they all increase monotonically over time, except for RHIC which shows a pronounced dip. Is there an identifiable cause for this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to proton beams, RHIC collides lots of different ion configurations at different energies.

The proton luminosity didn’t really go down:

[image]
 (From this [BNL RHIC overview page](https://www.rhichome.bnl.gov/RHIC/Runs/))

When running ions, the peak luminosity depends on species (really, on charge to mass ratio) and energy.

[image]

[image]

(You’re comparing the slopes in that last image)

So the apparent drop was primarily due to using the machine with new beam types to extend its physics life.